# Bonjour bridge with Avahi

Tags: networking, avahi, zeroconf

I have two subnets with different devices that announce themselves using the Bonjour protocol. Since these messages can be only broadcasted in the same subnetwork I installed the Avahi daemon. I enabled the reflector option and restarted the server but it won't work.

I must note that what I have is a machine running Ubuntu server 12.04 LTS with two interfaces, each connected to one of the two subnets. When the daemon start I can check with 'avahi-browser -ac' that my server is able to see every device in the two subnets, but for some reason the packages are not broadcasted.

Here it follows my config file:

```
[server]
use-ipv4=yes
use-ipv6=yes
allow-interfaces=p1p1,p3p1
ratelimit-interval-usec=1000000
ratelimit-burst=1000

[wide-area]
enable-wide-area=yes

[publish]

[reflector]
enable-reflector=no

[rlimits]
rlimit-core=0
rlimit-data=4194304
rlimit-fsize=0
rlimit-nofile=768
rlimit-stack=4194304
rlimit-nproc=3
```

And a small extract from the syslog (which to me seems everything's fine):

```
Feb 17 16:32:59 shuttle avahi-daemon[2108]: Registering new address record for fe80::82ee:73ff:fe67:e587 on p3p1.*.
Feb 17 16:32:59 shuttle avahi-daemon[2108]: Registering new address record for 192.168.28.27 on p3p1.IPv4.
Feb 17 16:32:59 shuttle avahi-daemon[2108]: Registering new address record for fe80::82ee:73ff:fe67:e546 on p1p1.*.
Feb 17 16:32:59 shuttle avahi-daemon[2108]: Registering new address record for 192.168.38.27 on p1p1.IPv4.
Feb 17 16:32:59 shuttle avahi-daemon[2108]: Registering HINFO record with values 'X86_64'/'LINUX'.
Feb 17 16:33:00 shuttle avahi-daemon[2108]: Server startup complete. Host name is shuttle.local. Local service cookie is 2224955595.
Feb 17 16:33:01 shuttle-bcn avahi-daemon[2108]: Service "shuttle" (/services/udisks.service) successfully established.
```

I even tried enabling IPv4 forwarding between the interfaces (via /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward) but I'm not able to see all the devices in the different subnets.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but in case someone else finds it with the same question...

I believe that you need to change

```
enable-reflector=no
```

to

```
enable-reflector=yes
```

and restart the avahi-daemon service.